# BIRT Report Dynamic Sorting Not Working

Tags: javascript, birt

I'm trying to dynamically sort the BIRT report columns with this following codes. but it is not woking. is there anything else I want to do?

I'm using Report Params "SortDir" & "SortKey" and in my table header coloumn using HyperLink.In hyperlink i'm using the following expression in "SortDir" param

```
if(params["SortKey"].value == "sortkeyvalue")
{
  if(params["SortDir"].value == "Asc")
  {
    "Desc";
   }
   else
   {
      "Asc";   
    } 
 }
 else
 {
   "Asc";
  }
```

beforeFactory Method I put this code

```
table = reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("mytable");
if (params["SortDir"].value == "Desc"){
  table.getListProperty("sort").get(0).setProperty("direction","desc");
}else{
  table.getListProperty("sort").get(0).setProperty("direction","asc");
}
```

Ana also include the PropertyEditor--->Sorting Tab include following the expression

```
 if(params["SortKey"].value == "sortkeyvalue")
 {
    row["coloumnname"];
 }
 else if(params["SortKey"].value == "sortkeyvalue")
 {
   row["coloumnname"];
 }
```